# How to use include-what-you-use on Debian 8.5

Tags: c++, debian, clang, iwyu

I'm trying to use include-what-you-use on Debian 8.5.  I made a test program that simply includes `<iostream>` and std::cout's "Hello, world" to the terminal.  When I invoke `iwyu` on it, I get the following:

> t1.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'iostream' file not found

Clearly it can't seem to locate the system headers.  I suppose I can force it by using the `-I` option, but I feel as though I shouldn't have to do that.  Requiring me to tell it where the system headers are leads me to believe that something else is horribly wrong and using `-I` is just treating the symptom and not the cause.

Incidently, I have verified that invoking clang to compile my test program works just fine.  So clang itself seems to work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does your `$PATH enviroment` include the folder where iostream is?

Comment: looks like someone has compiled and installed the compiler but not the standard library.

Comment: @Ripi2, no it does not.  Why would it need to be?

Comment: @RichardHodges, I didn't compile the binary.  I used the iwyu binary package that was in the Debian stable repo.  But anyway, like I said in the OP, clang can compile the test program just fine.  If the standard library wasn't properly installed, then that would've failed.